# Can't set titleView in Navigation bar center and scope of back button increased

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, titleview

I am trying to push a view controller and set its navigation bar's title but it is not centered due to long title being used i guess. Along with that, scope of the back button is increased till the title view, i.e if I tap with with Milestone's "M", it gets back though it frame is the same.

[image]

Bounds of back button are the same but its click impact is elongated.

[image]

Below is the code for how I am pushing the view controller.

```
 MilestoneDetailsViewController *controller = [[MilestoneDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MilestoneDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and in the MilestoneDetailsViewController, i set the title as following:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Milestone Details", nil);
```

Comment: Did you write any code for hiding back button text ?

Comment: best option is use your custom view instead of navigation bar

Comment: @Wolverine: I edited my question with the code.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum Can you show navigation bar of previous vc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back button is picking its size according to the title of previous viewController. you can change it to a empty String for example, in your previous viewController from where you are pushing write this code.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
       target:nil
       action:nil];
```

Comment: I already tried this, still it has got the same behaviour, "Project Details" is the title of the previous controller though.

Comment: Got the same behaviour wherever i put it.

Comment: You have to change the backButton text from previous viewController not from the one which is currently presented.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
UILabel* lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,40)];
lbNavTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lbNavTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Milestone Details!",@"");
self.title = lbNavTitle // here self.title is your navigation bar title
```

Comment: How is this any different from setting string directly ? Your piece of code is just picking the text lblNavTitle, not the alignment etc.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum here i just create one label and i give that label alignment to your  navigation bar title with alignment center

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum I believe that problem is not with the title, its with backButton size

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum what is problem with your backbutton ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    UIView *tView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 160 ,44)];

UILabel *bartitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, tView.frame.size.width, 40)];
[bartitleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[bartitleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[bartitleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[bartitleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Milestone Details!",@"")];
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@""];

[tView addSubview:bartitleLabel];
[tView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[self.navigationItem setTitleView:tView];
```